# How to change human readable attributes depending on context in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I know I can change the ActiveRecord names in a locale file, but is there a way to change them based on context rather than locale (while still leveraging locale files in the application)?

For a simple example (I have multiple circumstances where I need to accomplish this), if I have an address form in a wizard and a user selects a country, how could I change the label/error messages for a `:zipcode` attribute to display `"Zipcode"` to those who have selected United States, and `"Postcode"` to those who have selected United Kingdom?

Edit: What I mean is when a model attribute (country) changes, how to change the human readable attributes for (zipcode) based on the country selection. The users locale won't change (I am already making use of locale files for translations).

Comment: Best way to do this is to use i18n, Look at this post https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to localize is to use I18n, check this post: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization

**Basic I18n**

First add locales in you application.rb controller

```
config.i18n.available_locales = ["en-GB",  "en-US"]
config.i18n.default_locale = "en-US"
```

Then create 2 files `en-US.yml` and `en-GB.yml` under `config/locales`

```
# en-GB.yml
en-Gb:
  zipcode: "PostCode"

# en-US.yml
en-US:
  zipcode: "ZipCode"
```

Then in your controller, you will need to set dictionary that will be used for translation. It is defined with the `I18n.locale` variable.

```
# example when locale is passing through params
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = I18n.available_locales.include?(params[:locale]) ? params[:locale] : I18n.default_locale
end
```

And finaly in your views:
    <%= t('zipcode') %>

Or if you need in you ruby files:

```
I18n.t('zipcode')
```

**Localize ActiveRecord Attributes**

Same as above, you can create a active_record.en-US.yml under `config/locales`

```
# active_record.en-US.yml
en-US:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      your_model_name:
        zipcode: 'ZipCode'
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't word my example very well. I am already using locale files for general translations.

What I meant was, in a multi-stepped form (using one model), if the first step includes picking a country, and the second step includes editing the address fields, at that point, how do I change the humanized values? The end users locale won't change during this process, just some related attributes/context on the model.

Comment: Are the 2 steps on the same "page" ? Just want to know if you want to change it using javascript or if the server rendering the step 2

Comment: They are different actions/views operating on the same underlying model. Zip code was just one example (seems common enough that people may have faced it before), but there are other fields where labels/error messages change depending on another attribute, that simply switching locale for that action would conflict with.

Comment: I found a solution but not sure it is the best one and if it is a clean way to do. In you model you can add a custom_validator and handle the error like this `errors.add(' ', I18n.t('zipcode', locale: country.to_locale))`

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the other answer as I did end up using locale files as part of my solution.

What I did was a bit hacky, however:

1. Set locale to `{language}-{selected_country}` before the necessary request
2. Have specific overrides in those YAML files where necessary, fall back to standard attributes in base language file whenever possible.
3. Make use of `alias_attributes` in the `FormObject` to minimise the need for the above hack.